# Not able to delete records when there are related records in other table with foreign key

Tags: javascript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Getting the following error, tried `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` on the `@ManyToOne` relation

`[ExceptionsHandler] update or delete on table "resource" violates foreign key constraint "resource_skill_resource_id_fk" on table "resource_skill"`

**Resorce Entity**

```
import {
    BaseEntity,
    Column,
    Entity,
    Index,
    JoinColumn,
    JoinTable,
    ManyToMany,
    ManyToOne,
    OneToMany,
    OneToOne,
    PrimaryColumn,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    RelationId
} from 'typeorm';
import { Organization } from './organization';
import { AreaResource } from './area_resource';
import { Client } from './client';
import { EventResource } from './event_resource';
import { LocationResource } from './location_resource';
import { LocationResourceAssignment } from './location_resource_assignment';
import { ResourceSkill } from './resource_skill';
import { TeamResource } from './team_resource';

@Entity('resource', { schema: 'cccalpha1' })
export class Resource {

    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'first_name'
    })
    first_name: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'email'
    })
    email: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'background_color'
    })
    background_color: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'phone'
    })
    phone: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'last_name'
    })
    last_name: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'font_color'
    })
    font_color: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'full_name'
    })
    full_name: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'prefix'
    })
    prefix: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'middle_name'
    })
    middle_name: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'full_name_last_first'
    })
    full_name_last_first: string | null;


    @Column('boolean', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'inactive'
    })
    inactive: boolean | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'suffix'
    })
    suffix: string | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'fax_number'
    })
    fax_number: string | null;


    @Column('boolean', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'email_schedule_alert'
    })
    email_schedule_alert: boolean | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'cell_number'
    })
    cell_number: string | null;


    @Column('boolean', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'text_schedule_alert'
    })
    text_schedule_alert: boolean | null;


    @Column('text', {
        nullable: true,
        name: 'email_cell_address'
    })
    email_cell_address: string | null;


    @Column('uuid', {
        nullable: false,
        primary: true,
        default: () => 'uuid_generate_v4()',
        name: 'id'
    })
    id: string;


    @ManyToOne(type => Organization, organization => organization.resource, {})
    @JoinColumn({name: 'organization_id'})
    organization: Organization | null;


    @OneToMany(type => AreaResource, area_resource => area_resource.resource, { cascade: true })
    area_resource: AreaResource[];


    @OneToMany(type => Client, client => client.resource)
    client: Client[];


    @OneToMany(type => EventResource, event_resource => event_resource.resource)
    event_resource: EventResource[];


    @OneToMany(type => LocationResource, location_resource => location_resource.resource)
    location_resource: LocationResource[];


    @OneToMany(type => LocationResourceAssignment, location_resource_assignment => location_resource_assignment.resource)
    location_resource_assignment: LocationResourceAssignment[];


    @OneToMany(type => ResourceSkill, resource_skill => resource_skill.resource, { eager: true, cascade: true })
    resource_skill: ResourceSkill[];


    @OneToMany(type => TeamResource, team_resource => team_resource.resource)
    team_resource: TeamResource[];

}
```

**Resource Skill Entity**

```
import {
    BaseEntity,
    Column,
    Entity,
    Index,
    JoinColumn,
    JoinTable,
    ManyToMany,
    ManyToOne,
    OneToMany,
    OneToOne,
    PrimaryColumn,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
    RelationId
} from 'typeorm';
import { Resource } from './resource';
import { Skill } from './skill';

@Entity('resource_skill', { schema: 'cccalpha1' })
export class ResourceSkill {

    @Column('uuid', { 
        nullable: false,
        primary: true,
        default: () => 'uuid_generate_v4()',
        name: 'id'
    })
    id: string;


    @ManyToOne(type => Resource, resource => resource.resource_skill, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'resource_id' })
    resource: Resource | null;


    @ManyToOne(type => Skill, skill => skill.resource_skill, { onDelete: 'CASCADE' })
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'skill_id' })
    skill: Skill | null;

}
```

Comment: I don't find a question in your question.

Comment: @zenbeni My question was what is the right usage of `onDelete: 'CASCADE'` to avoid the error in case I'm doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did three things and deletion works great now.

1. Dropped all tables from the schema (Not sure if it was necessary)
2. Changed the way the primary columns are declared in the `Entity` as following,

```
// Old way
@Column('uuid', { 
   nullable: false,
   primary: true,
   default: () => 'uuid_generate_v4()',
   name: 'id'
})
id: string;
```

to

```
// New way
@PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
id: string;
```

3. Set `synchronize` to `true` in the module so that the DB is synchronized with the `Entity`

> synchronize - Synchronizes database schema. When synchronize: true is set in connection options it calls this method. Usually, you call this method when your application is shutting down.

P.S: May be the first step is not necessary but I was already down the path where I dropped the tables

Answer (score 0):

Synchronize: true => did the magic